# spec for update_all method ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write a spec that tests a function I used it in a task, this function should rename a json key and keep the old value of that key.

anyway I'm not able to making it pass.

my function:

```
module Database
  module JSONHelpers
    def change_json_nested_key(klass, base_field, nested_key, from_key, to_key)
      klass.where("#{base_field}->>'#{nested_key}' LIKE '%#{from_key}%'")
           .update_all(
             "#{base_field} = jsonb_set(\
             #{base_field}::jsonb,\
               array['#{nested_key}'],\
               (#{base_field}->'#{nested_key}')::jsonb - '#{from_key}' ||\
               jsonb_build_object('#{to_key}', #{base_field}->'#{nested_key}'->'#{from_key}'))"
           )
    end
  end
end
```

and my spec is:

```
  let(:old_key) { 'drawings' }
  let(:new_key) { 'picture' }
  let(:boxes) { {"#{old_key}" => '4'} }
  let(:move) { Move.create!(boxes: boxes)}

  let(:klass) { Class.new { extend(Database::JSONHelpers) } }
  subject { klass }

  describe '::change_nested_json_key' do
    before(:each) { subject.change_json_nested_key(Move, 'data', 'boxes', old_key, new_key) }
```

the function works outside of the spec, but in the spec doesn't. the `binding.pry` shows that the value hasn't changed.

Any idea what's wrong, or what's the rule here ?

Comment: where's your expectation? Did you forget to reload `move`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ( reload ) to update your instance after changing the values